# Subclassing the Perl DBI, overwriting the database handler in the calling script upon disconnection

Tags: perl, dbi

I have this problem:

pseudocode:

```
package a;

@ISA = qw(DBI);

package a::db;
@ISA = qw(DBI::db);
    sub prepare{
      #gets a $dbh object, which we can overwrite upon disconnection
      #so that the calling script gets a fresh and working dbh, 
      #through $_[0] = $newdbh;
    }

package a::st;
@ISA = qw(DBI::st);

sub execute{
  #gets a $sth object which we can rescue upon disconnection 
  #before the execute, but the calling script will have a faulty $dbh
}
```

calling script:

```
use a;
my $dbh = a->connect;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select 1");
$dbh->disconnect; #I detect this in the execute function
$sth->execute; #disconnect detected, reconnect -> reprepare and execute again 
               #(is done in the module a) = we're up and running!
```

Is there any way to affect the $dbh object without having to call $dbh->prepare again in the calling script?

My problem is also that I want to do this seamlessly because I want to fix the database handling in many projects by just using my new database module.

Is it at all possible?

Or could I maybe make the statement handler from a::prepare part of the ::db package as well? Which in turn would mean that the database handler from a::connect would have to be a statement handler as well, so that when I use connect I get an object with access to both prepare and execute. Then I could modify $_[0] in the a::execute to the new dbh object, which would mean that after the reconnect in the a::execute, the calling script would have a valid $dbh. Tried a lot of ways of doing this but I suspect the inner magic of DBI is making it hard...

Comment: What do you mean by "affect the $dbh object" ? Can you be more specific?   Do you just want to reuse a still valid/open database handle or are you reconnecting?  Maybe `DBI->connect_cached` is what you want or maybe something with bells and whistles like [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class)?

Comment: I mean the next time I use the $dbh/database handler in the script after the reconnect, it will not be valid in the case above because I have no way of "transferring" the valid database handler created in the execute subroutine in a::st to the script using the function.

Comment: Only after using prepare will the calling script get a valid database handler.. I was thinking if maybe perl had a way of magically setting the $dbh of the calling script... otherwise I have to rethink and maybe try to make both ::st and ::db part of the same package/object, but the DBI seems to have underlying protection against such things...

Comment: For instances of your DBI::st subclass to detect that their DBI::db has disconnected and to then reconnect and requery is all easy enough. After all the DBI::st knows which database handle it is associated with (`$sth->{Database}`), knows the SQL query (`$sth->{Statement}`), and knows about any bindings (`$sth->{ParamValues}`). However, if your database has disconnected you half-way through looping through a result set of 1000 records, reconnecting and re-querying the database will put you right back at the start of the result set. (Which may be being returned in a different order this time!)

Comment: ... So a better solution is to fix whatever is causing your database server to disconnect you in the first place. Too high load? Unreliable network? Ridiculously low time-out setting on queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing is a way to create a class that behaves identically to another class but with some refinements.

Your `a` class (could you think of a worse identifier?) doesn't seem to be anything like `DBI`, and I'm not surprised you're having difficulty expressing what you want in those terms. It sounds like you want an `a` object to *have* a `DBI` connection, not to *be* one.

So perhaps you could write

```
package a;

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

sub connect {
  my $self = {};
  $self->{dbh} = DBI->connect(@_);
  $self;
}
```

Where you go from here I'm not sure, as you've described a proposed solution rather than the problem itself

Comment: Yeah, I am subclassing so that I can just load the module and everything will seamlessly function like normal, only my new module will have reconnects and retries (deadlocks/innodb), and I have also written exceptions for when tables are locked or AutoCommit is off.

Comment: Accepting this since this is the only thing that seems to make sense, simply doing it right instead of hoping I can somehow magically bind or affect the database handler that is owned by the script, through my subclass..